The last activity timestamp (if answered) in visited questions doesn't differ from a non-visited link
I just observed the last activity timestamp on question list for visited links doesn't differ from the non-visited links if the activity is answering.

As you can see in the picture, both links are visited (the texts are violet). But the upper one has a gray timestamp (which is normal for a non-visited link).
I tried to visit other links with their last activity being "answered x mins/hours/days ago" and I found all of them suffer the same issue.
For activities like "asked" and "modified" the issue doesn't exist.
